# Old, yet we stand tall

Tags: knowledge, cipher, visual, lateral-thinking

This puzzle requires a specific answer which consists of 4 letters *only*. With the help of the image below(and the title) you will get the right one.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Really fun puzzle...thanks! The answer is:

> MOAI

Step 1:

> In the top diagram, "add" the top and bottom grids so that a pixel is white if the corresponding pixel in *either* of the top or bottom grids is white. Flipping this picture vertically gives a pixellated version of the text "RGYPBO".

Step 2:

> Noting that "RGYPBO" are the first letters of the colors used in the bottom two diagrams, use this as a key to the order in which to read the boxes in the second diagram. In this order, reading from top to bottom, it produces the message "LOOK FOR THE THREE WORDS HIDDEN INSIDE THE A-Z, WHITE BOXES, STARTING (WITH ABCD) IN TOP ROW".

Step 3:

> Copy the A-Z alphabet, left to right, top to bottom, into the white squares of the second diagram. The numbers in the upper left corners of the white boxes provide an order in which to read them. There is a box around the 1 in the "O" box to distinguish 1 from 16, but other numbers can be read unambiguously. Reading these letters in numerical order reads "OPEN GOOGLE MAPS".

Step 4:

> Read the third diagram, using the same color order "RGYPBO" as the second diagram, top to bottom, to produce a set of coordinates "-27.1258098,-109.4088548".

Step 5:

> Opening Google maps and entering the coordinates from step 4 yields a location on Rapa Nui (Easter Island). Those who are old, yet stand tall here are called MOAI.

Comment: Great job! You nailed it :)